# (Conditional) coin flips mean and variance

Tags: probability, statistics

Roll a fair die to obtain a random number $1 ≤ n ≤ 6$, then flip a fair coin $n$ times. Let $X$ be the random variable that expresses the number of heads in the coin flips.
Find the mean and variance of $X$.

> Since the coin flips are Bernoulli trials, the expected number for heads ($H$) and tails ($T$) are $\mathbb{E}[H]=\mathbb{E}[T]=n/2$.

Furthermore, $H$ (and $T$) is distributed as per the binomial distribution, which has mean $n/2$ and variance $n/4$,  ($n\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$).

I don't know how to combine this with the outcome of the die roll.
I have very elementary knowledge with probability and statistics, but I know, at least, that the coin tosses are independent of any other event.

(This is a problem I found in a Facebook group - not homework or anything).

Thank you!

Comment: [The law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) and the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance) may help

Answer (score 0):

We have $N \sim Unif\{1,6\}$, $X|N \sim Bin(N, \frac12)$

By law of total expectation:

$$E[X]=E[E[X|N]]=E\left[ \frac{N}2\right]=\frac12 E[N]=\frac12 \cdot \frac{1+6}{2}=\frac74$$

Also, by the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance), we have

\begin{align}Var(X) &= E[Var(X|N)]+Var(E[X|N]) \\
&=\frac14E\left[N\right]+\frac14Var(N)\\
&=\frac14 \cdot \frac72 + \frac14 \cdot \frac{6^2-1}{12}\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much; I would appreciate though a few more details, because, like I said, I only have very elementary knowledge of probabilities / statistics. I am quite good at combinatorics (because they are easy to understand and visualize) but statistics is not my strong point!

Comment: Hi, which steps is confusing?

Comment: I understand that $N$ follows uniform distribution in $\{1,6\}$ and that  $X|N \sim Bin(N, \frac12)$, but I don't understand the rest, about $E[X]$ and variance, that is, how we are going to do the calculations. Thank you!!

Comment: I used the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) and the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance). Perhaps read those posts first?

Comment: Maybe you should add $\mathsf P(X=0\mid N=1)$ for all values of $X$ and $N$?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh forgive me but this is too theoretical for me and I may not have the appropriate background to understand it. Maybe you can give me some more clues or at least give me the general formula and I'll try to figure out the rest of calculations. Thank you

Comment: Perhaps start by the total law of expectation. Is this statement ok? $E(A) = E(A|B)P(B) + E(A|B^c)P(B^c)$?